# Como utilizar diagrama de pacotes UML para montar relação entre sistemas?

Tags: uml, diagrama

Eu tenho o seguinte diagrama, que não está formatado seguindo nenhum diagrama UML. A finalidade dele é representar o funcionamento e ligação de cada parte da solução do problema (uma aplicação web para filtrar literatura cinza provinda de um processo de web-scraping).

[image: Diagrama original]

Preciso montar um novo diagrama com os processos da parte destacada utilizando UML. Sugeriram a utilização de diagrama de pacotes, por se tratar de uma representação de alto nível que relaciona diferentes sistemas. Essa é a primeira versão:

[image: Diagrama de pacotes UML (incorreto?)]

É correto relacionar esses elementos dessa forma, utilizando pacotes?

Answer (score 0):

Embora não tenha uma resposta exata sobre os elementos a utilizar eu entendo que o pacote é bem pertinente para representar partes inteiras, distribuídas de forma autônoma, e que pode ser um sistema inteiro, ou módulos separados dele, desde que visto como autônomo. Tenho um sistema que é composto de 2 sistemas web, um em WebForms e outro em MVC (mais novo). Tem uma pequena parte em Windows Forms, para impressão de etiquetas com QRCode, e um app em Angular com Ionic para uso em campo. Usamos o Report Server para nossos relatórios. Sendo assim, todos independentes, mas usando o mesmo banco de dados, ilustramos as partes como **pacotes**. E o sistema como um todo fica em grande **bloco**. Outra opção quando não há tanta independência física, mas de funcionalidade usamos o componente **módulo**. Então no pacote MVC temos os módulos de Manifestação, Implantação, Atendimento, Faturamento, etc.
Não sou especialista na UML, mas tem sido bem recebido por todos o uso acima citado. Se há formalmente elementos melhores para tais itens eu gostaria que informassem aqui para maior conformidade e correção dos modelos que uso.

Comment: Obrigada por compartilhar sua experiência. Fiz a mesma [pergunta no StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361542/uml-package-diagram-for-relationship-between-systems), acabei usando um diagrama menos formal, mas ficou entendido que o ideal neste caso seria utilizar mais de um diagrama UML.